# Interactive grid - write values ​in text field when clicked

Tags: oracle-apex

With a query I have 3 values ​​that I would like to process further. With the LOV, I only get a return value. Or you can use a plug-in, I've read.

How can I transfer the values ​​from column 1 to text field 1, column 2 to text field 2 and column 3 to text field 3 by clicking on any row in an interactive grid?

I currently have a dynamic action stored in the interactive grid - when you "click".
With "True" I have selected the action "Set value" and as Set Type "Dialog Return Item". Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way.

I am not yet very fit in dealing with APEX and I hope your help.

Marja

Comment: I found a solution. I was already on the right track, but I have to work with Execute Java ScriptCode and use it to return the value. Works perfectly! I thank you

Answer (score 0):

add three page items page_item1, page_item2 and page_item1

You can create DA on the interactive grid on event selection change
[Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAhOB.png)
and action execute JavaScript code
[JavaScript code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnPGK.png)
then write this code

```
var model = this.data.model;
for ( i = 0; i < this.data.selectedRecords.length; i++ ) { 
$s("page_item1", $v("page_item1") += model.getValue( this.data.selectedRecords[i], "COLUMN1"));
$s("page_item2", $v("page_item2") += model.getValue( this.data.selectedRecords[i], "COLUMN2")); 
$s("page_item3", $v("page_item3") += model.getValue( this.data.selectedRecords[i], "COLUMN3"));
} 


`
```